# rails autosave => true with new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a User model which has a has_one, autosave relationship with a UserContext model.

I create a new User model and a new UserContext model like this:

```
u = User.new
u.user_context = UserContext.new
u.save
```

I get a validation error saying:

user_context.user_id cannot be blank. user_id is nil because I have a new User record which doesn't yet have an ID.

I think rails is trying to save the user_context first and then user. How do I get around this in the most elegant fashion?

Comment: That should work. Rails is smart enough to save the associations first. In your UserContext to you specify `belongs_to :user`? It may be more helpful if you past the code of those two models.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have a validates_presence_of :user_id in my UserContext model. Removing that makes it work, but I don't want to allow creations of UserContext without a user_id.

Comment: Can you try doing? `uc = UserContext.new; uc.user = User.new; uc.save`

Comment: @dhruvg Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

2 years late, but thought I'd add this in case anyone comes across this in the future

```
u = User.new
u.user_context = UserContext.new(user: u)
u.save
```